# Does Apple authorised repair centre reapply the “IP68” rating fully, after changing battery?

Tags: iphone, battery, hardware, repair

I am thinking of buying a refurbished iPhone 13 Pro from an Apple-authorised service provider (I live in Portugal and there is no Apple Store). They said the battery of the refurbished unit will be at 90 to 93 percent. After buying the refurbished iPhone, I will pay them an extra 80 euros to change the battery to a new battery (they said all the parts in the phone are original Apple parts, and the new battery will also be original.

I checked Apple's website and saw their store name (it’s called FNAC) in the Apple authorised service provider list in Portugal.

We know that when we buy a “brand new” iPhone 13 Pro, it comes with an IP68 water and dust-resistant feature.

But, will the refurbished iPhone 13 Pro from that store have the “full IP68 protection”?  (They said their refurbished units have IP68 protection)

Apple puts the IP68 protection via adhesive glue around the screen, different kinds of gaskets, and other things.

My question is, will the refurbished iPhone 13 Pro from the “Apple authorised service provider” store (in Portugal) have the **exact same** IP68 condition as a brand new iPhone 13 Pro?

Comment: Probably not.  Apple themselves (per the [Tech Specs page](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/FGH63LL/A/refurbished-iphone-12-64gb-black-unlocked?fnode=2c00f681a77630f92b9ae922688a1b3bd2afe3db391314a6a4fb1712590932d0f646b9f18d4516a5f6ea76fb833f126d3e861ea95d57bf0c528ef2a3981328ff7564d7ed6a572f611fc72c82db08b78088746f58044f731a47da30538b15d2c6)) give IP68 water proofing.  I don’t know if Apple is willing to speak for 3rd party providers.

Comment: But, I am not saying “3rd party providers” . I said “Apple authorised service provider”

Comment: Those are 3rd party. I’m not referring to independent repair shops